# Compile razor views for middlewares in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics netstandard library

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-middleware

I am trying to edit some parts of [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics library](https://github.com/aspnet/Diagnostics)

But I cannot edit razor files like [CompilationErrorPage.cshtml](https://github.com/aspnet/Diagnostics/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics/DeveloperExceptionPage/Views/CompilationErrorPage.cshtml)

Even after a solution or project compilation (command line & Visual studio GUI) the file [CompilationErrorPage.Designer.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/Diagnostics/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics/DeveloperExceptionPage/Views/CompilationErrorPage.Designer.cs) does not change.

The only thing I have seen is that they use this tool

```
"tools": {
    "RazorPageGenerator": "1.1.0-*"
 }
```

And it is invoked during [build process](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/aspnetci/diagnostics/build/1.0.828#L386)

Do you know what I missed?

Answer (score 0):

It is a .Designer.cs file. It is managed and generated by the IDE. You are not suppose to change it.

Comment: It's a specific case for middlewares, you can see librairies like Hangfire or StackExchange.Exceptional, they use RazorGenerator plugin (file "custom tool" property in visual studio). There is no "custom tool" property with netstandard librairies
http://csharpcorner.mindcrackerinc.netdna-cdn.com/UploadFile/97fc7a/article-precompiled-razor-view-using-razorgenerator-mvc-and/Images/13.jpg